# Cloning a list (definition and items) over SOAP?

Tags: python, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010

Due to paranoid Sharepoint administrators we have the need clone an existing list over the SOAP API ourselves..Is there an (easy) way to accomplish this? We already have a Python based API for accessing the list items and field descriptions over SOAP - I am not sure if this is enough for create a 1:1 copy ourselves...is there a better more straight forward way?

Comment: SharePoint 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not "cloning" by creating a list template through the UI or a list definition with features and creating instances from that?

Comment: Are you cloning the list to another SharePoint instance (Ex: Prod to Dev)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an "easy" way to do this.  You would have to retrieve the schema from the web service, and modify it before instantiating it somewhere else.  It depends a bit on where the clone operation is destined, but you will have to change the schema in some way to some degree, regardless of the destination.

Beyond that, it depends on how customized the list is.  If you are using custom content types, you'll have to clone them as well, with all the same difficulties.  If it has custom views, you'll have to do the same trick with them.  If you have custom forms for your views, I think you're hosed.  I don't know of any way to get those forms from the web service interface.

Comment: I disagree, there are quite competent integration components what will transform this task into a simple sql to sql synchronization job.

Comment: @Trikks: I'm pretty sure Ben is talking about cloning the entire list... not just copying data. It is unclear what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Trikks: yes - there are backup and migration tools out there, but based on the context of the question (he mentioned Python, and web services), I took it to mean that he wants to write custom code to transfer (by copy) a list (schema + views + data) to an arbitrary location.  That is not trivial.

Comment: Agree to that, thats very complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to clone a list is to save the list as a template (in the list settings in sharepoint that is) and include it's content. This way you get a "List template" which you can download and install wherever you want to.

To clone list data through another system is a completely other task but not impossible. I replicate data with PHP between several SharePoint installations using the Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint (http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/).

The outwards interface for the SharePoint installations is a very simple WCF service. In example

```
public string ExecuteScalar(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (SharePointConnection connection = new SharePointConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sharepoint_sales"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SharePointCommand command = new SharePointCommand(sql, connection)) 
            {
                var returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (returnValue != null)
                {
                    return returnValue.ToString();
                } else { 
                    return null;
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //add your own exception handling
        return null;
    };
}

public bool ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (SharePointConnection connection = new SharePointConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sharepoint_sales"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SharePointCommand command = new SharePointCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //add your own exception handling
        return false;
    };
}
```

To insert stuff from the php-world to SharePoint code can look something like this

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://wcf.labs.trikks.com/Camelot.svc?wsdl");

$sql = array('sql' => "INSERT INTO contactform (title,email,company,message) 
        VALUES ('Name','email@example.net','Company','A test message!')");

$post = $client->ExecuteNonQuery($sql);
echo($post->ExecuteNonQueryResult); // true (1) on success
```

So, retrieving and inserting data becomes quite, well, simple.

I could write some example .net service to demonstrate list synchronization if it will help you.